# Best practice for tfs single files

Tags: tfs

We use TFS for our source control, which works fine for projects, however in addition to WinForms solutions, we also write short SQL statements that are used in isolation by the business. My question is, what would be best practice for storing these in TFS, my immediate thought is to create a 'SQLs' project and just store them that way, but is that overkill? Is there support for just adding a folder to TFS?

I found this link: http://geekswithblogs.net/slock/archive/2007/07/05/113704.aspx

But this seems to be adding items to an existing project / solution.

Many thanks,

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio to add a "New Folder" where every you want.

[image: New Folder]

Then you can fill the folder full of files using File Explorer in Windows.

When you have done that, just use the "Add Items to Folder" option.

[image: Add Items to Folder]

Select the files you want and click Finish:

[image: Add Files]

Now if you look at your pending changes you will have all your files ready to check in.

**One final note**

When you are working on these files, you will have to use Source Control Explorer or the [Power Toys](http://aka.ms/tfpt) shell extension to "check out" the files to remove the read only flag (don't clear it yourself). If you upgrade from TFS 2010 to 2012/3 then there are local workspaces available that mean you don't need to check out the files before editing (just like subversion).

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive answer, I'll go this route

Answer (score 1):

How about giving [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) a go?

One of the many features is a Windows Explorer shell extension that allows you to add, check out, etc. without having to use Visual Studio at all.  You can simply put your files in a folder, and add the whole lot to TFS from the context menu.

If you've ever used TortoiseSVN, it's very similar and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Sir Crispalot, I will definitely look into TFS power tools, especially as I do miss Tortoise SVN :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) alot when working with SQL scripts, then you could also use the MSSCCI Provider, which provides source control integration to SSMS.